# jQuery - Restore the removed select option

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I have multiple dropdown menus with the same options. If one option was selected, other dropdown menus will not show the selected option. When I tried to reset the selected option, it did not restore the removed select option.

HTML part:

```
<select id="selectNumber" class="selectbox">
    <option value="0">Choose a number</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
<select id="selectNumber2" class="selectbox">
    <option value="0">Choose a number</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```

Javascript part:

```
$(".selectbox").change(function(){
    var selectedIndex = $(this).index();    
    var myVal = $(this).val();
    $(".selectbox").each(function(i){        
        if (selectedIndex != i){
            $("option", this).each(function(){                
               if (myVal == $(this).val() && myVal != 0){
                   $(this).detach();
               }else{
                   $(this).prepend();
                   //not work

               }

            });
        }
    });
});
```

[the demo but not working](http://jsfiddle.net/planetoid/7Ssu7/)

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Have you tried using .hide() and .show()? Just asking.

Comment: Why are you using `.index()` and what is `i`?

Comment: @human IE will not support hide/show of `option` tag

Comment: @lan Using .index() for counting the select tag

Comment: @PlanetoidHsu Ahh okay, I was confused by the variable name `selectedIndex`, as they usually refers to the selected `<option>`'s index. So what is `i`?

Comment: @lan i is the i-th select tag; selectedIndex is the selected select tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you want

```
/* store options */
var $selects = $(".selectbox");
var $opts = $selects.first().children().clone();


$selects.change(function () {       
    var myVal = $(this).val();
    if (myVal !='0') {
         $selects.not(this).children('[value="'+myVal+'"]').remove();
    }else{
        var replaceVal=$(this).data('currVal');
        $selects.not(this).append( $opts.filter( '[value="'+replaceVal+'"]').clone())
    }
    $(this).data('currVal', myVal);

});
```

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/7Ssu7/8/

**EDIT Version - keeps sort order**

```
/* store options */
var $selects = $(".selectbox");
var $opts = $selects.first().children().clone();


$selects.change(function () {
    /*create array of all selected values*/    
    var selectedValues=$selects.map(function(){
        var val=$(this).val();
        return val !=0? val :null;
    }).get();


    $selects.not(this).each(function(){     

        var $sel=$(this), myVal=$sel.val() ||0;        
        var $options=$opts.clone().filter(function(i){
            var val=$(this).val();         
            return  val==myVal || $.inArray(val, selectedValues) ==-1;
        });
        $sel.html( $options).val( myVal)
    });  

});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/8uunN/1/

Comment: But the option order is changed.

Comment: @IswantoSan can certainly add sorting to it, but OP didn't suggest that and was proposing `prepend`. Feel free to modify... at least will work in IE

Answer (score 0):

When you do a detach(), the object is removed and needs to be put into a "global" variable to save as a reference.
For your purpose, you can use .hide() and .show() as it retains the object in the list, without causing a DOM insertion or removal (so definitely better for performance).

Answer (score 0):

Well, your current code is not work, because you are not store selected value in another dropdown list. Also, like others said, use `hide` and `show` instead of `detach` and `prepend`.

You can see my solution in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Ssu7/6/) (tested in firefox)